# Interpretation of probabilities from logistic regression in Credit Score Card modelling

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I was trying to understand the probabilities output by a logistic regression in credit scorecard, let us say that I have performed Vintage analysis and identified the performance period as 6 months , and Bad rate is defined as 90DPD , so when I perform logistic regression for incoming new customers , the probabilities would define the probability that a customer will go Bad in the next 6 months ( which comes from performance period) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would hold if you have the same priors in train and test population. However this is not the case for most of credit scoring cases. In the train data, you have customers that are accepted by model, so a higher good to bad ratio. In test data (when you apply your scorecard for new customers), this ratio is typically very different. Therefore the probabilities predicted by the logistic model can not directly used. 
There is no easy solution for this (look at reject inference problem). A simple improvement would reweighting/downsampling the train data to match the good/bad ratio of the test data (if you have an approximation for that).